# synchronicity javascript error while accessing the database twice in an endpoint using node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a company that have a job opening, and other users that want to work there have to make orders to that job position. Overy order has an id of the user that make´s it. I want to also show the name of that user when the company wants to see all the orders for a job.

So, what I was doing was just get all the orders with `Order.getOrder`, and then  get `name` and `email` from user for every order and add it to what I am going to return.

The error I´m getting is  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in the last `then`

```
 router.get("/orders", verifyToken, (req, res) => {   
    Order.getOrders(req.userId, (err, rows) => {
        for (x in rows) {
            console.log(rows[x].id);
            User.forge({id: rows[x].id}).fetch({columns:['email','name']}).then(user => {
                rows[x].nameTester = user.get('name');
                rows[x].emailTester = user.get('email');
            });
        }  
    }).then(function(err, rows) {
        res.json({orders: rows});
    });
});
```

And this

```
Order.getOrders = (userData, callback)=>{
    if (connection) {
        const query = ...sql query...
        connection.query(query, [userData], (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                callback(null, result);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Does your `getOrders` function return a `promise`?

Comment: I updated with my getOrders.

Comment: Either use a callback or promises, not both.

Comment: I tried instead of callback(null, result), Promise.resolve(result) but still  doesn´t work. What changes do you suggest?